# Project Publish submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I developed my project with Asp Mvc.

 Now, I changed my controller Action and Published Project in server but my >Dll and my website Don't Change.

in the past When I Change Controller and Publish
In Output Panel up-to-date has value  but now that is zero

Comment: What method to publish did you use? FTP?  Is it possible that the file was locked and not updated?

Comment: No I Publish in File system

Comment: I would then check to be sure that you don't have a hidden build error.  Sometimes if you accidentally selected "use last good build" it will show an error, but still publish/compile

Comment: I See this in My Warning:Severity Code Description Project File Line Column Suppression State
Warning  Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. MY_MVC_APPLICATION